# My assembly has been granted the FullTrust permission set, and I'm running it on the Internet zone

Tags: vb.net

I want to know what permissions are granted for my assembly when I run it directly from the c:\ drive, and when I run it from the default C$ share.

I understand that the assembly will be granted the FullTrust permission set by default if it runs from the local file system.

Problem is, the assembly has been granted the FullTrust pemission set, and I'm running it on the Internet zone. How did that happened?

The assembly is located in the default c$ share. So, to run it, I typed the following command into the Command prompt: \\127.0.0.1\C$\Assembly.exe.

I was expecting that the assembly would be denied the Registery, the FileIO, and the EventLog permissions; but they're all granted for my assembly.

Answer (score 1):

What version of the framework are you using ?

Applications running from a network share on .NET 3.5 SP1 and later, will receive a grant set of FullTrust by default.

Comment: I'm using .NET framework 3.5. And if that's the case, how can I adjust that setting, so that applications running from a network share will not receive FullTrust?
Please help!